# Python Merge dictionaries of same length but different keys

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have two dictionaries of same length but not the same keys like below

```
dict1 = {"integervalue": None, "floatingValue": None, "stringValue": None}
dict2 = {"0": 10, "1": 0.1020, "2": "XXX"}
```

I need to update the values of second dictionary to first (dictionaries of same length) and using zip to achieve like below

```
for (k, v) in zip(dict1, dict2):
  dict1[k] = dict2[v]
```

this does the job and produces output as below

```
dict1 = {"integervalue": 10, "floatingValue": 0, "stringValue": "XXX"}
```

or is there any better way to achieve without zip ?

Comment: Can't reproduce this. Your code gives me a `dict1` like: `{'integervalue': 10, 'floatingValue': 0.102, 'stringValue': 'XXX'}`

Comment: No it doesn't convert anything.

Comment: oh yeah ! its not converting the type but is there any fastest way to do the same ?

Comment: Is there a defined correspondence between the keys in the first and second dict? i.e. is `"integervalue"` always paired up with `"0"` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve what I think you are after but it does not account for if there are multiple int, float, or str values in the `dict2`, it modifies the `dict1` a bit, and it uses a third dictionary.

```
dict1 = {str: 'stringValue', int: 'integerValue', float: 'floatingValue'}
dict2 = {"0": 10, "1": 0.1020, "2": "XXX"}
output = {}

for k, v in dict2.items():
    output.update({
        dict1.get(type(v)): v
    })
```

Output: `{'integerValue': 10, 'floatingValue': 0.102, 'stringValue': 'XXX'}`

---

**EDIT** Could also do `for v in dict2.values()` since I am not using the `k` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys always have the same correspondence like in the example you showed, I'd actually make that explicit instead of relying on insertion ordering, which may cause problems. Something like:

```
key_translation = {
    "integerValue": "0",
    "floatingValue": "1", 
    "stringValue": "2"
}

dict1 = {"integerValue": None, "floatingValue": None, "stringValue": None}
dict2 = {"0": 10, "1": 0.1020, "2": "XXX"}

for key in dict1:
    dict1[key] = dict2[key_translation[key]]

print(dict1)
# {'integerValue': 10, 'floatingValue': 0.102, 'stringValue': 'XXX'}
```

Comment: Works fine but If its nested dictionary of multiple levels I have to maintain key_translation dictionary for them same right ?

Comment: and in my case dictionary is generated dynamically where I cant have key transalation mapping anyways this is helpful